# How do I stop images in my emails from stretching on mobile devices?

Tags: html

I am an HTML novice so I took a free responsive template and tweaked the colours to fit my branding, along with a few other fixes. All displays fine on a monitor, but when viewed on a mobile device, my images are distorted and stretched. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you adding both height and width properties in your images. You need to provide any one of them so other gets adjusted automatically and image does not distort.

Comment: Check img tag inline width and height property.  Is it written in px?

Comment: Link to the template you used?

Comment: Add some code if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to always set image width. There are two ways, by img width or height attribute or with css inline-style. (In mailings, if you use css always write it inline)

```
<img width="200" src="http://example.com/img/logo.jpg" />
```

Or with CSS:

```
<img style="width:200px;" src="http://example.com/img/logo.jpg" />
```